# Как применить is_match к строке входящего потока Rust?

Tags: rust

Пробую применить трейт regex к stdin но, выдает ошибку `error[E0382]: use of moved value: 'line'`

Думаю напутал что то с типами данных

```
extern crate regex;

use regex::RegexSet;
use std::io::{stdin, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let set = RegexSet::new(&[
        r"([0-9]){3}",
        r"([a-z]){3}",
        r"([A-Z]){3}",
        r"(.*[0-9].*){4}",
        r"(.*[A-Z].*){4}",
        r"(.*[a-z].*){4}",
    ]).unwrap();

    let stdin = stdin();
    let test_string = "Test me once";

    println!("{}", set.is_match(test_string));

    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let mut line_str = line.unwrap();

        println!("{}", line.unwrap());
        println!("{}", set.is_match(&line_str));
    }
}
// End of main.rs
```

Сообщение об ошибке

```
   Compiling lfr v0.1.0 (file:///home/Projects/hck/Rust/lfr)
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `line`
  --> src/main.rs:29:24
   |
27 |         let mut line_str = line.unwrap();
   |                            ---- value moved here
28 | 
29 |         println!("{}", line.unwrap());
   |                        ^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `line` has type `std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

---

Нашел решение

```
for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
    let mut line_str = line.unwrap();

    println!("{}", set.is_match(&mut line_str));
}
```

Как я понял, "время жизни" переменной истекло, удалил один из `println!` решив проблему.

Comment: Тут дело не во времени жизни, а в том что строки не копируются, а "перемещаются". Почитайте про [семантику перемещения в Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#ways-variables-and-data-interact-move). Вообще в сообщении об ошибке которое вы привели все очень хорошо объяснено.

Comment: @aSpex Спасибо, перечитал. Прочитывал док пол года назад, потом не было времени на создание кода, сейчас решил переделать питон-баш костыли на Rust.

Answer (score 1):

> Как я понял, "время жизни" переменной истекло, удалил один из println! решив проблему.

[Метод `Option::unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) поглощает `self` при вызове (принимает просто `self`, а не, например, `&self`), так что дважды вызвать его при хранении [не-`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) типа нельзя. [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) как раз не копируемый.

Для двух `println` было бы логично один раз развернуть строчку и использовать уже развернутый вариант дальше:

```
for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
    let line = line.unwrap();
    println!("{}", line);
    println!("{}", set.is_match(&line));
}
```

На всякий добавлю, что если по какой-то причине хочется сделать `unwrap` `Option`'а без поглощения значения, даже несколько раз, то можно, например, использовать метод [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref), который для `Option<T>` вернет `Option<&T>`:

```
fn main() {
    let opt_s: Option<String> = Some("abc".to_string());
    let ref_to_opt_s: Option<&String> = opt_s.as_ref();

    // теперь можно сколько нужно раз вызывать `unwrap` у `ref_to_opt_s`:
    println!("1: {}", ref_to_opt_s.unwrap());
    println!("2: {}", ref_to_opt_s.unwrap());
}
```

[Playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=388732e8220a17412dfbc79bbf479bb5&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: Как Указал aSpex переменная "двинулась" (извиняюсь за каламбур). Как я понял если повторяются конструкции типа `let a = 1; let b = a ; let c = b;` Rust сохранит только последнюю "связь". Извиняюсь за терминологию, я просто не от программистов.